# Is angular.js considered too large for simpler use cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would angular.js be considered too large to use for simpler use cases, for example just for a certain
portion of a web page which is not a SPA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes. For small tasks like you describe here, I prefer to use simpler two-way-binding-frameworks such as [KnockoueJS](http://knockoutjs.com/). It is super easy and you can achieve quite a lot of cool funtionality.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question is yes and it is discussed in the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

Comment: I am assuming the bold font implies I am asking a question without prior research. I would like to tell you I have been reading and working on angularjs for 2 months, and still havent come across that in the documentation. Thank you.